# How to solve Web Deploy - IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED

Tags: iis, webdeploy

Using Web Deploy, I encountered this problem as recorded in the server event log:

> IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED
>
> The user '[my user]' is not authorized for the path '/[my site]'.
>
> Process:WMSvc User=NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When setting up the site, I had misspelled the site name in IIS.
Confusingly, the error reported contained the *correct* spelling! (must be obtained from the url passed to web deploy)

Hence the web deploy command didn't match the site name in IIS.